# How do you resolve ambiguity between template operators?

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I've looked far and wide and everyone seems to have a slightly different issue than me.

For simplicity say I have a template struct `Complex<X>` and I want it to have overloads for real values and at least other Complex. As a rule, operations between `double` or `Complex<double>` and `Complex<float>` (on either side) should return `Complex<double>`. I'm currently using deduction guides that work quite well for this, but other options are `std::common_type_t<X,Y>`, `decltype(std::declval<X>()+std::declval<Y>())`, etc.

```
(1) `auto operator+(X const&)`
(2) `friend auto operator+(X const&, Complex<X> const&)`
(2) `template<class Y> auto operator+(Y const&)`
(3) `template<class Y> auto operator+(Complex<Y> const&)`
(4) `template<class Y> friend auto operator+(Y const&, Complex<X> const&)`
```

Here's the problem. If I write (1-2), then `Complex<float>` sees doubles as floats. If I make that (2-3), then apparently adding `Complex<double>` is ambiguous between (2,3,4). Non-template operators wouldn't be ambiguous, but please assume there are too many template arguments to name.

Next I thought that the CV/references were to blame, but making (1-2) operators of `X` changed nothing. This appears to be opposite the behavior of `auto x` which won't be a reference.

I tried adding assertions like `static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<Y>)` to (1-2) but they don't participate.

Answer (score 0):

After trying static assertions that didn't help from the function body, I thought before I move on I should try enabling/disabling functions another way. I remember this approach not working correctly in the past, so I didn't try it until much too late.

```
template<class Y>
auto operator+(Complex<X> const& x, Complex<Y> const& y)
-> std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic_v<Y>,
    Complex<decltype(std::declval<X>(), std::declval<Y>())>> {/*...*/}

template<class Y>
auto operator+(Complex<X> const& x, Y const& y)
-> std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic_v<Y>,
    Complex<decltype(std::declval<X>(), std::declval<Y>())>> {/*...*/}

template<class Y>
friend auto operator+(Y const& y, Complex<X> const& x)
-> std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic_v<Y>,
    Complex<decltype(y, std::declval<X>())>> {/*...*/}
```

This isn't the code I'm using, I've paraphrased everything. Please let me know if I made a mistake somewhere.

This table shows the sum type of the row and column correctly. If either field type has double precision then so does the result; the same goes if either type is complex.

```
    add          f           d      Complex<f>  Complex<d>
     f           f           d      Complex<f>  Complex<d>
     d           d           d      Complex<d>  Complex<d>
Complex<f>  Complex<f>  Complex<d>  Complex<f>  Complex<d>
Complex<d>  Complex<d>  Complex<d>  Complex<d>  Complex<d>
```

As an aside, if you define assignment operators like `operator+=`, then `Complex<X>` only goes on the left (no friend functions) and only returns `Complex<X>&` (type is fixed.) It should probably accept the same types as `operator+` or use `operator+` directly, so it only rounds at assignment/conversion.

```
template<class Y>
auto operator+=(Y const& y)
-> std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic_v<Y>,
    Complex>& { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want to use `std::complex` for some reason. Now you have to decide the type of `complex<float>+double`; is it going to loose some data?

1. If the result is `complex<float>`, then precision bits of `double` are lost and large values are clamped to `INF`.
2. If the result is `double`, then the imaginary part is gone.

Thus, the best of both worlds would be `complex<double>`. A closer looks reveals that your problem boils down to conversion/promotion to/from numeric types. You are going to need conversion constructors:

```
#include <concept>
template<std::floating_point numeric>
class complex{
public:
    constexpr complex(numeric const r=0,numeric const i=0);

    template<std::floating_point othern>
        requires std::constructible_from<numeric,othern>
        explicit(!std::convertible_to<othern, numeric>)
    constexpr complex(complex<othern> const&);
    //...
```

Now you can simply define:

```
    //continue class declaration:
    friend auto const& operator(complex rgt, complex const& lft)
        {return rgt+=lft;};
    complex const& operator+=(complex const&);
    //...
```

This approach hits two birds with one stone. For completness I would define one conversion operator too:

```
    //still inside class complex:
    explicit constexper operator numeric() const
        {return this->real();};
    //...
```

The `explicit` specifiers - in declaration of conversion constructors and operator - conducts correct deduction and  required implicit. conversions

Comment: I wonder if you saw my answer. The goal was to extend to both double precision and complex numbers if either were present. It looks like I got it. In any case, yes, I used `Complex` because `std::complex` was familiar... in reality it's `Quaternion` and beyond and I didn't want to distract from the problem. (I think recursive `Complex` and other nesting templates together may break my approach, it's hard to say what the ground field is at a certain level.) As an aside, is C++20 fully supported anywhere? I could get a lot more done with concepts.

Comment: Regarding your own answer, mine still applies. With quaternions nothing much changes. You may need to insert complex numbers inside conversion chain. IMFAO, the problem is not in binary operations, but rather in conversion chain (which must be carefully managed with explicit/implicit ctor/operators). By the way, **boost** provides you with **octonions** as well as **quaternion**, in case you need to speed things up. As of now the latest version of all major platforms on pc support most C++20 features; you may need to specify a compiler switch on command line or in the build script however.

Comment: Instead of **n^2** cases, you should deal with **n**. That's why conversion chain is the primary route to take.

Comment: `convertible_to` et-al might not be the correct test for `explicit` though. You may need a trait/concept to detect narrowing conversions between types.

Comment: You can make the argument, but that's not a hard fact. More cases mean you can cut all the corners where they differ. For instance, you chose to double the cost of every real value you used by treating both as complex; why not treat them all as quaternion, all octonion, etc.? Or more realistically, just treat them all as matrices? Different priorities. Going in the opposite direction, when 3D vectors and quaternions interact, I save that 25%. At every level of dual multiplication I omit the zero quadrant and save another 25%.

Comment: I'd also like to recommend against the conversion operator to real - you can get away with it in one direction, but coming back you may have an imaginary component or not, and how you convert that value isn't obvious at all. Should it be a projection, and what kind? Should it be magnitude instead? It relies on semantics where there isn't a canon/convention, to gloss over the fact that the complex is a catchall and you can't tell what values are dummies.

Comment: As long as size is static and relatively small, compiler optimizer can be trusted. For more complex cases - like matrix special treatments will be needed.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to say, no, compiler optimizations aren't going to remove fields that are sometimes used.

Comment: Temporary objects may be totally removed, if no observable side effect exists. That's how optimizer works. Conversions create tempories, but since temporaries are created from immediate values, there is enough information for the optimizer to do the cleanup. Had the source of temporaries injected entropy into the process, they could not be removed. But you are just creating a series of zero bytes, and the compiler knows it.